# Jquery navigation, how does it run?

Tags: javascript

my "click preventer" doesn't work to slide down the subnavigation:

```
var nav = $('.nav li.mega');
nav.children('.subnav-container').hide();
nav.click(function () {
event.stopPropagation();
    nav.children('.subnav-container').hide();
    $(this).children('.subnav-container').show();
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rzf7w69u/36/

Comment: You forgot to take in the `event`.

Comment: What do you exactly mean?

Comment: `function(event)`

Comment: Thx, that workted: http://jsfiddle.net/rzf7w69u/41/ but how can I slide up and down?